# more efficient method of substring calculation for advice

Tags: python, algorithm

My code works and I am looking for smarter ideas to be more efficient?

For string similarity, it is defined as longest common prefix length,
for example, "abc" and "abd" is 2, and "aaa" and "aaab" is 3.

The problem is calculate the similarity of string S and all its suffixes,
including itself as the first suffix.

for example, for S="ababaa", suffixes are "ababaa", "babaa", "abaa","baa","aa"
and "a", the similarity are 6+0+3+0+1+1=11

```
# Complete the function below.
from collections import defaultdict

class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children=defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.isEnd=False
class TrieTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=TrieNode()
    def insert(self, word):
        node = self.root
        for w in word:
            node = node.children[w]
        node.isEnd = True
    def search(self, word):
        node = self.root
        count = 0
        for w in word:
            node = node.children.get(w)
            if not node:
                break
            else:
                count += 1
        return count

def  StringSimilarity(inputs):
    resultFormat=[]
    for word in inputs:
        # build Trie tree
        index = TrieTree()
        index.insert(word)
        result = 0
        # search for suffix
        for i in range(len(word)):
            result += index.search(word[i:])
        print result
        resultFormat.append(result)

    return resultFormat
```

Comment: I think your question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Andrea is right, however, I suggest [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: @Rockybilly, I think edit distance is different from what I am asking? I only need to check prefix. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you change the wording a bit to use "substring" rather than "suffix" since suffix implies just the beginning of the word, and substring implies a smaller part of the string that could show up anywhere in the string

Comment: Done, thanks @KevinWells. If you have smarter more efficient ideas, appreciate for sharing. :)

Comment: @Rockybilly - I think this is just a coding challenge with a contrived string similarity: [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-similarity)

Comment: @dwanderson, nice catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 efficient approaches you may wish to consider:

### Suffix Tree

Compute the suffix tree of the original string.  Then descend down the principal path through the suffix tree, counting how many paths depart from the principal at each stage.

### Suffix Array

Compute the suffix array and the longest common prefix array.
These arrays can be used to compute the longest prefix of any pair of suffices, and in particular the longest prefix between the original string and each suffix.

### Z function

The output you are trying to construct is known as the Z function.
It can be computed directly in linear time as shown [here](http://e-maxx-eng.github.io/string/z-function.html) (Not Python code obviously):

```
vector z_function(string s) {
    int n = (int) s.length();
    vector z(n);
    for (int i = 1, l = 0, r = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (i <= r)
            z[i] = min (r - i + 1, z[i - l]);
        while (i + z[i] < n && s[z[i]] == s[i + z[i]])
            ++z[i];
        if (i + z[i] - 1 > r)
            l = i, r = i + z[i] - 1;
    }
    return z;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Interested to explore all of your recommendations. For your advice about suffix array -- "Compute the suffix array and the longest common prefix array", what exactly do you mean array here? For example, in my input string, "ababaa", what is the array?

Comment: A suffix array is an array providing the starting positions of each suffix, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array).  In practice suffix arrays can normally be used to do the same type of tasks as suffix trees, but they are often faster.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I take time to study the Z function twiki you provide, I am confused by this statement, "For this, we observe that the substrings s[l…r] and s[0…r−l]match. This means that as an initial approximation for z[i] we can take the value already computed for the corresponding segment s[0…r−l], and that is z[i−l].", my confusion is how the information we get when calculating segment s[0…r−l] is used? Appreciate for more comments. Thanks.

Comment: And Peter, did more analysis and especially confused by one point. I think it is possible there is another l2, where value z[i-l2] is larger than z[i-l], which could even skip more elements to compare, and sub-string [l2...r2] not necessarily to be the right most matched segment as sub-string [l...r] did. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Peter, mark your reply as answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
def similarity(s, t):
    """ assumes len(t) <= len(s), which is easily doable"""
    i = 0
    while i < len(t) and s[i] == t[i]:
        i += 1
    return i

def selfSimilarity(s):
    return sum(similarity(s, s[i:]) for i in range(len(s)))

selfSimilarity("ababaa")
# 11
```

Comment: Thanks dwanderson, why you method is faster than mine Trie tree? :)

Comment: Ihaven't actually had a chance to use your method, so I'm not positive. One potential issue is just overhead - instead of using a `str`, which is a builtin and very lightweight; each letter of each suffix was a `TrieNode` which has a `defaultdict` which has a single `key` and `value`, which is another `TrieNode`... it's a lot of object instantiation and creation (and hence dereferencing), vs just a letter-by-letter `strcmp`. As @btilly mentions - you aren't reusing any of the `TrieNode`s, so it's simpler.faster to just do the straight test.

Comment: Actually efficient implementations, apparently (and probably what @Peter di Rivaz is suggesting, though the info there is pretty lacking): [this lecture](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2011/cmsc858s/Lec02-zalg.pdf)

Comment: Thanks dwanderson, I read the reference and did more analysis and especially confused by one point. I think it is possible there is another l2, where value z[i-l2] is larger than z[i-l], which could even skip more elements to compare, and sub-string [l2...r2] not necessarily to be the right most matched segment as sub-string [l...r] did. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: @LinMa wish I could help but I don't actually know the `Z algorithm` myself; I just found the link and it seemed relevant :).

Answer (score 1):

It takes a lot of work to build the `TrieTree` object.  Skip that.  Just do a double loop over all possible starting points of a match, and all possible offsets where you might still be matching.

Building complex objects like that only makes sense if you'll be querying your data structure many times.  But here you aren't so it doesn't pay off.

Comment: Thanks btilly, people are discussing Z function and prefix array, and wondering if you have better more efficient ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa Notice how the Z function code has a while loop inside of a for loop?  That is exactly the double loop I was referring to.

Comment: Thanks btilly, I read the reference and did more analysis and especially confused by one point. I think it is possible there is another l2, where value z[i-l2] is larger than z[i-l], which could even skip more elements to compare, and sub-string [l2...r2] not necessarily to be the right most matched segment as sub-string [l...r] did. Any comments are appreciated.